# Rename hostname

Tags: active-directory, hostname

If you rename the PC's hostname at the PC while it is connected to the domain, will it find that original hostname in AD and rename it there as well?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Active Directory should automatically update with the new workstation name.  If you have multiple domain controllers in different sites, it may take some time for the change to replicate across all controllers (depending on topology and settings).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will rename the computer account in the domain.